# How come when x=abc, [[ $x > 123 ]] && echo yes || echo no returns yes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, fedora

I understand that it is a string comparison, however i dont understand how "abc" & "123" are compared against each other. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989373/bash-testing-if-a-string-is-greater-than-another-how-does-it-work-internal

Comment: The strings are compared against each other lexicographically — look up what that means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because, inside `[[…]]`, the operators < and > do string comparison.

In doing an string comparison the order is given (basically) by the alphabet, where a is before (smaller) than b and smaller than c: `a < b < c`.
Numbers are usually before (smaller) than letters: `1 < 2 < a`

So, as an `a` sorts after a `1` `abc` is greater than `123`:

```
$ [[ abc > 123 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Or, as you present it:

```
$ x=abc    y=123
$ [[ $x > $y ]] && echo yes
yes
```